# How can I bulk update varchar data based on a pattern in a MS SQL 2012 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m using MS SQL Server 2012 and I need to bulk update varchar data in a single column based on a text pattern.

Basically my single column contains comma separated variable length text data (see below) and I need to strip out the some of the data based on a pattern. For example, I have “ProductA-106, ProductB-107” and need to transform it to “ProductA, ProductB” stripping off the “-Number” text.

Can you help me to do this? Thanks a lot.

- Existing:

**Single Column**

```
ProductA-106, ProductB-107
ProductC-108, ProductD-109, ProductDA-109, ProductDB-109
ProductF-1011, ProductE-2015
```

- End result:

**Single Column**

```
ProductA, ProductB
ProductC, ProductD
ProductF, ProductE
```

Comment: Outside some rather complex replace logic in a function - I don't see many good ways of doing this. So to think out of the box, I think it would actually be faster/easier to simply make a small application (or SSIS package) which extracts the data and then you can do the replacement logic in a higher level language which might support the replacement logic easier.

Comment: Your problem is caused by your bad database design. Don't store multiple values in a single column.

Comment: Is it always of the form ProductX or is it more complicated? You'll probably need to do it in a few passes, also I suggest loading it into a new table and working on it there rather than updating the source directly. Post some more detailed info on the exact format of the data. In the given examples, the answer is trivial because the products are all the same length but I bet this is not the case with your real data.

Comment: What I would do is use an `UNPIVOT` to extract the data into single rows (including using DISTINCT to remove duplicate ProductD in your second example), clean it and `PIVOT` it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect example why you don't want to have a database design like that.

It can be solved, but it is not easy, pretty or fast:

Create this function:

```
CREATE function dbo.f_cleanup (@a varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
BEGIN

WHILE @a like '%-%'
SELECT @a = STUFF(@a, dash, comma - dash, '')
FROM 
(
  SELECT CHARINDEX('-', @a) dash, 
         CHARINDEX(',', @a + ',', CHARINDEX('-', @a)) comma
) x

RETURN @a
END
go
```

Test here:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(SingleColumn varchar(100))
INSERT @t VALUES
('ProductA-106, ProductB-107'),
('ProductC-108, ProductD-109, ProductDA-109, ProductDB-109'),
('ProductF-1011, ProductE-2015')

UPDATE @t
SET SingleColumn = dbo.f_cleanup (SingleColumn)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Result:

```
ProductA, ProductB
ProductC, ProductD, ProductDA, ProductDB
ProductF, ProductE
```

Comment: i thought the desired outcome for `ProductC-108, ProductD-109, ProductDA-109, ProductDB-109` was `ProductC, ProductD` and not `ProductC, ProductD, ProductDA, ProductDB`

Comment: @BrettSchneider it was a choice between what the text said and what the end result showed. I went with the text.

Answer (score 1):

This would be much easier if your data was structured correctly - ie: your products in a single table, and related to your other table by IDs in a separate join table.

```
update yourtable
set yourfield = replace (yourfield, '-', '')

update yourtable
set yourfield = replace (yourfield, '0', '')

update yourtable
set yourfield = replace (yourfield, '1', '')

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the update:

```
declare @sep char=','
;with x as (
    select *, left(col, charindex('-', col)-1) as new_col
    from TableOne
    cross apply (
        select substring(ColOne, n, charindex(@sep, ColOne + @sep, n) - n) as col,
        row_number() over (order by n) as id
        from numbers 
        where substring(@sep + ColOne, n, 1) = @sep
        and n < len(ColOne) + 1
    ) x
),
y as (
    select ColOne, substring(col_list, 1, len(col_list)-1) as res
    from x
    cross apply (
        select x1.new_col + ', ' as [text()]
        from x x1
        where x1.ColOne = x.ColOne
        order by id
        for xml path('')
    ) y(col_list)
)
update y
set ColOne = res
```

Note that I'm using [Numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) for parsing.

Comment: sorry how should this be if the table is called TableOne and the column is called ColOne? I can't get this to work. Thanks

Comment: if I simply update the update statement at the bottom it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, I now the the error: "Invalid object name 'numbers'" - any ideas?

Comment: Last line of my answer, there is a link (Numbers table), click on it.

Answer (score 0):

create a function that will take care of it all:

```
create function doit (@a varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @out varchar(max)
    declare @tt table (c varchar(max))

    -- split the data, cut off the end and distinct it
    set @a = @a+','
    ;with data as (
         select SUBSTRING(@a,1,CHARINDEX(',', @a)-1) as a
              , substring(@a,CHARINDEX(',', @a)+2, LEN(@a)-CHARINDEX(',', @a)) as b
         union all
         select SUBSTRING(b,1,CHARINDEX(',', b)-1) as a
              , substring(b,CHARINDEX(',', b)+2, LEN(b)-CHARINDEX(',', b)) as b
           from data
          where CHARINDEX(',', b) > 0
    )
    insert into @tt
    select distinct SUBSTRING(a,1,8) c from data

    -- loop through the distinct data and concatenate it

    declare @c varchar(max)
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT c
    FROM @tt

    OPEN cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @c

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
        if (@out is null) set @out = @c else set @out = @out + ', ' + @c
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @c
    END   

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

    return @out
end
```

then update your table with it:

```
update yourtable
   set thecolumn = doit(thecolumn)
```

Comment: creating a function to take care of business is a great idea. But this is way too complicated

Comment: @Brett Schneider: Hi, I get error trying to create your function. Can you help? Error1: Must declare the table variable "@t". Error2:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: i forgot the semicolon before the with. should work now.